# Redis atomically pop and add to another set

Tags: redis

Is there a way to atomically move a member from one set to another set, returning the member that was moved? Basically like a LPOPRPUSH that is available for lists. I saw this LUA script

```
redis.replicate_commands()  -- needed since we call SRANDMEMBER below
local value = redis.call('SRANDMEMBER', KEYS[1])
if value then
    redis.call('SMOVE', KEYS[1], KEYS[2], value)
end
return value
```

Is this the best way to do this? I'm also wondering if SPOP/SADD could be used as well and what would be the benefit of one over the other.

Comment: Do you mean a random member? If so, yes, I'd go with that Lua script.

Comment: That script is atomic. It's your best bet.